# Firebase realtime database : how to check if child value exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Given the document below.

```
website:{
    uid1:{
        foo:"bar",
        username:"joff"
    },
    uid2:{
        foo:"bar2",
        username:"karla"
    }        
}
```

I am trying to check if the `username` already exist using the query below.

```
var ref = db.ref('website');
var queryString = 'joff';

ref.orderByChild('username').equalTo(queryString).once('value', function(snap){
    if(snap.exists()){
        // exists
        return
    }
    console.log('available');
})
```

This approach is working without a problem, if I change the `queryString` accordingly I get the result that I want if it exists or not.

Firebase's default query limit is 100 and I can change it to my liking according to the documentation.

But what if I will query though a let's say `10,000` documents? I cant use paginated query here, because what if the query match is on the 2nd page? How do I handle such amount of data? Will it take too long before it respond? What is the right approach to do such query.

**PS**

I strictly need the data model to be the same as the given above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that use of `equalTo` generated a "smart" query, and so the query limit wouldn't be factor in determining if record exists.  I'm not positive though. Have you actually verified that having more than 100 records, with your 'joff` being at 100+ in the ordering, results in no match?

If that is the case (which would be very surprising), then you could probably restructure your query something like this:

```
ref.orderByChild('username').startAt(queryString).endAt(queryString).once('value', function(snap){
    if(snap.exists()){
        // exists
        return
    }
    console.log('available');
})
```

... but again, I don't think that is required when using `equalTo`.

Comment: Hey! Actually you are right. I tested it with `limitToFirst(100)` and 'joff' was on 100+, actually it seems like that `limitToFirst()` function doesn't matter anymore if you are using `equalTo()`. Sorry for not testing the data properly. Thanks kailatech. :)